# Are questions about vulgar phrases on-topic and welcome?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is this question appropriate?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90/is-this-question-appropriate)

May we ask questions pertaining to words and/or phrases that most people might consider offensive?

Comment: Reopen voters: I think the answers there cover the general case. Please leave a comment here if you don't agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was discussed in [Is this question appropriate?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90/is-this-question-appropriate) and the EL&U dicussions it links to.

The highest-voted answers say:

> The discussion of no words, however offensive, should be prohibited on a site discussing language.
>
> However in the knowledge that this site is likely be used by students in schools and in other environments where such language would not be appreciated, at least the more obscene words should not be used in question titles out of courtesy. If a question title can't be reworded to avoid the word without being pointlessly vague, it should be asterisked.

and

> I think a good middle ground to not offending anyone would be to "censor" swear words in question titles whenever possible at best by choosing a sensitive phrasing and avoiding Asterisks (like in *sh***).

So vulgar phrases are fine, but try not to include them in the question title.

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate. Maybe you could do so too?